# show wpf dialog in own runspace from external file

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I have this proof of concept powershell script it will work in it's current form and will display a blank dialog but themed with wpf-ui library.

If I change `$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)` to `$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader **$xaml2**)` so it adds the same xaml code as `$xaml` but from a file it will not open a dialog.

I've tried all sort of ways to get it to work but can't seem to figure out why.

```
$Global:syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$newRunspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash", $syncHash)

$Global:Current_Folder = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

Add-Type -Path "$Current_Folder\Wpf.Ui.dll"
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
        [xml]$xaml = @"
    <ui:FluentWindow xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ui="http://schemas.lepo.co/wpfui/2022/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Wpf.Ui.Controls" Title="WPF UI" Width="800" Height="500" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <ui:FluentWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Wpf.Ui;component/Controls/FluentWindow/FluentWindow.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Wpf.Ui;component/Controls/TitleBar/TitleBar.xaml" />
                <ui:ThemesDictionary Theme="Dark" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ui:FluentWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ui:TitleBar Name="TitleBar" Title="Test App" Margin="0" ShowMaximize="False" ShowMinimize="False">
        </ui:TitleBar>
    </Grid>
</ui:FluentWindow>
"@
        function LoadXaml($filename) {
            $XamlLoader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
            $XamlLoader.Load($filename)
            return $XamlLoader
        }

        $xaml2 = LoadXaml "$Current_Folder\simplegui.xaml"

        $reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
    
        $syncHash.Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

        $syncHash.Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
        $syncHash.Error = $Error
    })
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$psCmd.BeginInvoke()
```

Comment: Your separate runspace doesn't see the caller's `$Current_Folder` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working code

```
$Global:syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$newRunspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash", $syncHash)

$Global:Current_Folder = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

Add-Type -Path "$Current_Folder\Wpf.Ui.dll"
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({

        param($FolderPath)

        function LoadXaml($filename) {
            $XamlLoader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
            $XamlLoader.Load($filename)
            return $XamlLoader
        }

      $xaml = LoadXaml "$FolderPath\simplegui.xaml"

      $reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
    
     $syncHash.Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

        $syncHash.Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
        $syncHash.Error = $Error
    })
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$psCmd.AddParameter("FolderPath", $Current_Folder)
$psCmd.BeginInvoke()
```